# React useMemo not returning correct memorized value

Tags: reactjs, storybook, react-usememo

Every time the component re renders the variable initalValues is console logging a different value, though the useMemo function is never running (The `console.log(options, 'here')` is never being console logged. If it did re run the value would be correct but it seems to be getting overwritten at some point randomly or retrieved from memory wrong.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Component code.

```
const initialValues = useMemo(() => {
    console.log(options, 'here');
    return options.filter(item => item.state).map(item => item.value);
}, [options]);
const initSingleValues = useMemo(() => defaultValue ? [defaultValue.value] : [], [defaultValue]);

console.log(initialValues, initSingleValues, 'init');
```

Code sandbox. When you toggle a checkbox, it adds it to the initialValues memorized value.

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-playground-forked-o20e5s?file=/Component.js

Comment: Could you share with `CodeSandbox` or something like that?

Comment: Perhaps initialValues is mutated somewhere else.

Comment: Whats the problem ? `useMemo` doesn't have to re run as the provided dependency ( `[options]` ) is same over time.

Comment: @Jordan, please check this [`CodeSandbox`](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-playground-forked-kkzzll?file=/Component.js)

Comment: @BikasLin That seems to work, but can you say why the link was being maintained between the different uses?

Comment: `curr.push(value);` is mutating your `values`-state in `handleMultipleChange`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const initialValues = useMemo(() => {
  console.log("here");
  return options.filter((item) => item.state).map((item) => item.value);
}, [options]);

  console.log(initialValues, "init");
const [values, setValues] = useState(
  chooseMultiple ? [...new Set(initialValues)] : initSingleValues // NOT JUST initialValues
);
const [showError, setShowError] = useState(false);

useEffect(() => {
  setShowError(false);
  setValues(chooseMultiple ? [...new Set(initialValues)] : initSingleValues); // NOT JUST initialValues
}, [chooseMultiple, initialValues, initSingleValues]);
```

As you can see from the above the `code snipet`, I use `[...new Set(initialValues)]` for `setValues`, not just `initialValues` to creat an absolutely another array.

Comment: This works and can be shortened to just the basic spread operator

e.g. 
instead of `[...new Set(initialValues)]`

it can just be ``[...initialValues]

Comment: But any chance you can go further on the actual problem here?

Comment: Without `[...new Set(initialValues)]` or `[...initialValues]`, the `values` and `initialValues` have the same `reference`/`address`. So updating `values` causes updating `initialValues` without running `useMemo`.

Comment: After looking in a bit more detail it looks like the actual problem is caused by calling `values.push(value)` in a set state function.

The value in state links to the momised array and therefore modifies the initialValues.

Comment: Thank you, been trying to figure this out for hours.